# Is it legal to use handheld radios to listen to airport frequencies in Australia?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio, australia

I am a student pilot at ABX ([YMAY](https://skyvector.com/airport/YMAY/Albury-Airport)) in Australia. It is a single engine aerodrome with three frequencies:

- 123.25;
- 125.80; and
- the ATIS frequency

I live very close to the airport, directly under the base/final turn. Would I be able to purchase a handheld radio that I could use to listen to the ATC and practise my radio calls? Is it legal?

Comment: ICOM makes scanners that can receive that band, and they seem to sell them in Australia: http://www.icom.net.au/receiver_ic-rx7.html. May not be the cheapest option, but seems  to answer the "can I" question.

Comment: You should make basic research before considering asking on this website. It would have saved the first part of your question (possibility of purchasing), and perhaps the second part (legality explained in the notice or other documents provided with such purchase)

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but take a look at liveatc.net

Comment: For the questions about legality, range etc. you might try posting on [ham.SE](http://ham.stackexchange.com/) too, because those seem like general questions about radio use in Australia.

Comment: You can use any basic scanner that includes the "aviation band" (AM) and has a squelch. As this is a receiver only, you won't have any legality question to solve. Icom and Yaesu are indeed good brands for radio hardware, but this is not required for such short distance.

Comment: @mins -- this is not necessarily true. The standards in the US might be different than those in Australia. There is one case where Icom has released a product in Australia that does not conform with the relevant Australian standard: http://www.acma.gov.au/theACMA/engage-blogs/engage-blogs/Spectrum/Supporting-aviation-communications-and-operations   So while all handhelds that operate on the frequency would probably work, they might not be legal.

Comment: @CJBS: Not compliant with *all* requirements doesn't tell much about the problem. But in general Icom a renowned brand. According to Wikipedia, it's [legal to listen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanner_%28radio%29#Australia) to any frequency in Australia, but private phone conversations.

Comment: @mins I'm not sure of the exact details -- the link referred to some minor interference problem. My point is that it might not be legal to just buy a handheld receiver in the US and then use it in Australia, even though it would work (as the frequency bands are the same).

Comment: I don't see where the US are mentioned in the question. It looks like the OP lives in Australia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Aeronautical License issued by the [Australian Communications and Media Authority](http://www.acma.gov.au/) (ACMA) is required in order to operate a handheld aviation-band VHF transceiver in Australia.

> An aeronautical licence is issued to authorise a station that:
>
> - is not fixed to an aircraft;
> - is operated on aeronautical frequencies;
> - is operated for purposes relating to the operation of an aircraft, or
>     airport or aerodrome operations; and
> - in relation to an aircraft
>     includes a mobile station operated on board the aircraft or on the
>     ground in communication with aircraft.
>
> An aeronautical licence is
>   necessary to authorise the operation of stations providing:
>
> - air traffic control services;
> - aerodrome radio information services;
> - private company radiocommunications; and
> - other airport or aerodrome
>     services.

Reference: [ACMA](http://www.acma.gov.au/theACMA/aeronautical-licences-guidelines)

The Australian-based [recreationalflying.com](http://www.recreationalflying.com/tutorials/comms/licence.html) tutorial website may also provide more useful information.

(Note: This applies for a transceiver -- i.e. transmit & receive -- rules may be different for receive-only).

Comment: Receiving [seems legal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanner_%28radio%29#Australia). Indeed transmitting (or owning a transmitter) on aviation frequencies is not permitted, unless you are authorized.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it would be legal in Australia to buy a scanner to listen to the aviation band. If you want one that transmits you will probably need a license to operate it if not buy it, but then you really don't want to be transmitting anyway.

Personally I would not think it's worth the money. Listening can be interesting but it gets old quickly and you don't learn as much as you might expect - RT work makes more sense in context. My personal experience is that the hard part of RT is not knowing what to say but getting it out in the cockpit when you are also flying and navigating as the same time, and that only comes with experience.

If you are taking lessons why not ask if you can borrow a handheld radio from your training organization? They probably have one or two lying around.

Comment: `I'm sure it would be legal in Australia`, what makes you say that?

Comment: Scanners are legal in most democracies, sometimes with a permit. They are for sale in australian pilot stores and ebay as well, so the balance of evidence would indicate it's legal to buy them.

Comment: @GdB I'm aware, but they are illegal in Germany and the UK. I think they're the only ones, however, it's still legal for pilots to buy secondary radios for use *in flight*, which is why you find them in pilot stores there as well. Especially given the heavy UK influences in Australia, it is a valid concern and I believe it warrants backing up the claim. I know LiveATC is broadcasting from all states in Australia, so I'm pretty sure you're correct, but still.

Comment: I'm not sure about Germany but scanners are legal in the UK.

Comment: I believe Germany and the UK have similar laws (I'm guessing you'll find them among the wiretapping laws), in that the devices as such are not illegal, but it's illegal to listen to air traffic frequencies unless you're involved in... well.. air traffic, and disseminate any information received to third party. They're idiotic laws, no doubt, that's not the point I'm trying to argue.

Comment: I live in the UK and I know of no laws or regulations which would prevent you from buying and using an air band scanner.

Comment: I quick Google search tells me it's called the `Wireless Telegraphy Act`, don't know the letter of the law, but most hits starts out by saying it's illegal to listen unless you're licensed to do so. Don't know what constitutes a license.